resConfigs() in build.gradle.kts is deprecated
I am setting a new languages mode for Compose Multiplatform Project. But
resConfigs("uz", "ru") function is giving me a deprecation notice, what to use?
Last times I used only old build.gradle file. I am using this article: https://medium.com/@fierydinesh/multi-language-support-android-localization-in-app-and-system-settings-change-language-e00957e9c48c

So this method is in BaseFlavor class, need to be using resourceConfigurations field.
defaultConfig {
   ...
   resourceConfigurations.addAll(listOf("uz", "ru"))
   ...
}

